# azure kubernetes https mix contents

Tags: azure, kubernetes, https, lets-encrypt, nginx-ingress

After I configured my `Azure` cluster to use the `Nginx Ingress controller` with `Let'sEncrypt SSL` my browser failed to fetch data from the backend "Mixed content", what is the best practice in such as case:

- move my backend to another cluster and run it over HTTPS?
- is there any way to allow my frontend that running over HTTPS to talk to my Backend pod?
- is there any way to run my backend over HTTPS in the same cluster?

Please help or tips :)

Comment: What do you mean by "mixed content"? Are you using AKS? Could you elaborate your questions? Move backend to another cluster but frontend will be in the old cluster? Q2, you want to force using HTTPS? Please elaboreate Q3 also.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply: Mixed content = your browser blocks the request to the backend because your frontend runs over HTTPS and backend runs over HTTP. I am using AKS yes, what I mean to move my backend to another separate container and run it over HTTPS to solve the issue, but I believe that I can keep it in the same cluster and run it over HTTPS (I don't know how?), my problem how to allow the frontend request the backend in a production scenario. it works fine in my dev machine.

Comment: It would be possible to provide your configuration? What exactly error you received?